# How to use the Azure Cache Service (preview) from Java

Tags: java, azure, memcached, azure-caching

I'm interested in using the Azure Cache Service (preview) from Java. The only docs I can find are about using it via .Net. The article [Run your Memcache app with Windows Azure Cache Service (Preview)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn386122.aspx) suggests it's possible through the memcached protocol, but I haven't succeeded in connecting. It seems that I need a Memcache client shim that might not be available for Java.

Is it possible to use the cache service from a Java application? We're using spymemcached if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://aka.ms/JavaAzureTutorial) you can find guide that demonstrates how to migrate PetClinic to Azure and use memcached via Simple Spring Memcached as a back-end to Spring Cache.